# Do something depending on the observable

Tags: knockout.js

```
  // HTML
  <button class='btn btn-success uppercase btn-lg active' data-bind="click: showVideoTool, css: {active: activeVideoTool}">Video Tool</button> 

  // Javascript
  self.showVideoTool = function() {
    // Checking if the value is true then make it false
    if (self.activeVideoTool == true) {
      self.activeVideoTool(false);
    } else {
      self.activeVideoTool(true);
    }
  }
  self.activeVideoTool = ko.observable();
```

As you see the code, I want to capture the current value of the activeVideoTool observable in order to know if I will make it `true` or `false`

I must be doing something wrong here. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Your logic doesn't match your comment. You are checking `self.activeVideoTool` and then setting it to `true` if it's `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (self.activeVideoTool == true)
```

`self.activeVideoTool` is an observable:

```
self.activeVideoTool = ko.observable();
```

It's a function, not a property. To get it's value you need to call the function:

```
if (self.activeVideoTool() == true)
```

This is a pretty common gotcha for knockout because when you declare a binding, knockout will automagically unwrap your observables for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a computed observable.

change:

```
  self.showVideoTool = function() {
    // Checking if the value is true then make it false
    if (self.activeVideoTool == true) {
      self.activeVideoTool(true);
    } else {
      self.activeVideoTool(false);
    }
  }
```

to:

```
  self.computedShowVideoTool = function() {
    // Checking if the value is true then make it false
    if (self.activeVideoTool == true) {
      self.activeVideoTool(true);
    } else {
      self.activeVideoTool(false);
    }
  }

self.showVideoTool = ko.computedObservable(self.computedShowVideoTool, self);
```

when activeVideoTool changes in the future, it will trigger the computedObservable function.